# How-to test a list query with Firebase Firestore Rules Simulator

Tags: firebase, google-cloud-firestore, firebase-console, firebase-security

I'm trying to simulate a list type query with Firestore Simulator for testing my database rules.

I've configured correctly the Firebase Firestore `userid` used in the simulation (a get request executes successfully) but the result I get when I use a list query type is `Simulated data access denied`.

How is it the the way to run a list type simulation?

I suspect the problem is the format/value of the Location field, see pitcure below, but I've really not idea of what it is wrong.

[image]

Answer (score 4):

As far as I know it is currently not possible test query-based security rules in the simulator. It sounds like a great feature request though, so I recommend [filing it](https://firebase.google.com/support/contact/bugs-features/).

Comment: I just filed one.